# Inline Javascript code not executed when JSP page crawled by Google bot

Tags: javascript, tomcat, post, get, bots

I have a `JSP` page `p.jsp` that contains an inline call to a `Javascript` function `f()`:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      my_namespace.f();
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

This `f()` function sends a `POST` request to one of my `Tomcat webapp servlets` `S`:

```
s_url = "S";
xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", s_url, true);
xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange =  my_namespace.fEnd;
xmlHttpRequest.send();
```

In Tomcat's log (`localhost_access_log.<date>.txt`), I observe the following line:

```
66.249.66.41 - - [date] "GET /my_webapp/p.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 4264
```

Sometimes, I also observe:

```
66.249.66.41 - - [date] "POST /my_webapp/S?param=value HTTP/1.1" 200 125
```

But not systematically, rather barely actually...

Why is the `Javascript` code not always executed?
`66.249...` being a `Google bot`, is it possible that the `GET` it performs is not the same as the one that is performed when using a Web browser?

Comment: There are 100s of ways to retrieve an HTML page via a GET and only a couple of them auto-run javascript *after* retrieving the page.   So, yes, the "GET" is the same, but what it does *after* that is relevant (eg the browser will run the javascript).   So while google-bot does run js, it could be that it blocks the xmlHttpRequest rather than the js itself.